# How to filter a list within another list MVC LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an issue filtering a List Property within another list.
I'm trying to use Linq.

I have a list of documents, each one of them has a list of authors.
I have a searchString parameter that i get from the view that I want the last name of the author to equal. I was able to do it with the other properties of the class documents, but I'm not able to do it with the list.

this is my code:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchBy,string searchString)
{
    db.Documentos.Include(l => l.Pais);
    db.Documentos.Include(l => l.Etiquetas);
    db.Documentos.Include(l => l.Autores);
    var documentos = from m in db.Documentos select m;
    if (searchBy=="Titulo"&& !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        documentos = documentos.Where(s => s.Titulo.Contains(searchString));
    }
    if(searchBy =="Fecha" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {                
        documentos = documentos.Where(s => s.Fecha.ToString().Contains(searchString));
    }
    if(searchBy == "Autor" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        documentos = documentos.Where(x => documentos.All(y => y.Autores.All(a => a.Apellido.Contains(searchString))));

    // this doesn't return anything, I cant filter with this.
    }
    return View(documentos.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Any` method.

```
documentos = documentos.Where(d => d.Authors.Any(f => f.LastName == searchString));
```

This will give you the list of documents for which any of the author last name is equal to the search string. If you are not looking of for the exact value for the lastname, but a substring, you can use `Contains` method.

```
documentos = documentos.Where(d => d.Authors
                                    .Any(f => f.LastName.Contains( searchString)));
```

Comment: @EmiL if it worked, you probably want to mark the answer accepted so it helps other people. Here is more info on why accepting answer is good: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work